# Substring Time Formatting

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time, formatting, sql-server-2008-r2

Currently I am using this script to pull a time out of a column:

```
    (RIGHT('0' + ltrim(RIGHT(convert(varchar,cast(SUBSTRING(A.DocSign, CHARINDEX('^', A.DocSign) +1, 19) as datetime), 100), 7)), 7))
```

What this returns is a time formatted like this 10:34AM - It is also converting military time to standard time in this code, and appends it to additional items I am pulling out of columns such as the date, last name, etc. I need the time to display as 10:54:00 AM

So essentially I need to add :00 (always zeros) to the end of any of the times and add a space between the zeros and the AM or PM that is coming in.

I am not very good at formatting, so I am having trouble with this one. Any suggestions?
(I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without trying to rewrite your expression, I'll just [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) the ':00 ' in.

```
STUFF(
   (RIGHT('0' + ltrim(RIGHT(convert(varchar,cast(SUBSTRING(
    A.DocSign, CHARINDEX('^', A.DocSign) +1, 19) as datetime), 100), 7)), 7)),
6,0,':00 ')
```

An alternative is to replace `PM`/`AM` with the zeroes embedded, i.e.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(
   (RIGHT('0' + ltrim(RIGHT(convert(varchar,cast(SUBSTRING(
    A.DocSign, CHARINDEX('^', A.DocSign) +1, 19) as datetime), 100), 7)), 7)),
'PM', ':00 PM'),'AM', ':00 AM')
```

Comment: That does work but what if I take the zeros off a PM time such as 03:45PM to 3:45 PM and I wasn to still insert the :00 in the correct spot?

Comment: I have added an alternative, which assumes there is no leading space before AM/PM.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Worked great.